# How to execute AWK in TCL list with variables?

Tags: shell, awk, tcl

I need to run a few commands from terminal via a TCL script. This TCL script works fine.

```
set cmd_list [list {mkdir testdir} {cd testdir} ]
set dataportInterface "eth0"
lappend cmd_list [list ifconfig -a | grep -m 1 $dataportInterface]
```

However, as soon as I add the awk command, it starts failing.
Error is "Failed : extra characters after close-brace".

```
lappend cmd_list [list ifconfig -a | grep -m 1 $dataportInterface | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[:]"} { print $1 } END {}' | xargs -t ethtool -S]
```

I have tried several possibilities, but none of them work. For example, if I try

```
lappend cmd_list {  }
```

then, `$dataportInterface`'s value `eth0` is not taken.

I tried putting a `\` in front of all special characters (`: " ' [ {` and that threw the error `$1 not recognized`. I put the `awk` command in `{{` brackets and that didn't work either. (`error: doesn't recognize {{awk`)

What is the correct way to go about this, and why?

Comment: Quote the entire `ifconfig ...` command in `{...}`?

Comment: In that case, `$dataportInterface` is not changed to eth0. However, if I hardcode `eth0`, it works. (But that's not what I'm looking for)

Comment: Fair enough. You'll need to use something to format your string then. Also you appear to have a stray `]` after `$dataportInterface` in that `ifconfig` command.

Comment: Removed the stray `]`. That was a SO typo.

Comment: How are you running that list of commands?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes have no significance to Tcl - try changing '...' to {...}

Comment: @EtanReisner: wrapping the argument to `awk` in braces will not interfere with variable expansion in the argument to `grep`.

Comment: I understand what this answer was intending to say now. It should, in light of my comment and the response, be written more clearly and explicitly. In that it should explain what the issue is more specifically. Why changing the single quotes to `{}` (in place) will help. etc.